# Export null value as xsi:nil within a xml report

Tags: xml, reporting-services, null, rdl

I am using SSRS and I have a report and one of the string fields is nullable. Default the XML report removes the element from the xml when the values are DBNull in the database. But the prefered way would be to have the xml as followed:

```
<value xsi:nil = "true"/>
```

Is there a way to achieve this using SSRS?

Comment: Not sure if this is a lame question.. but won't wrapping the string with an isnull in your dataset fix this? isnull(yourstringcolumn,'') as yourstringcolumn

Comment: @Harry No this turns the value to an empty string, which when turned into xml gives a  <stringcolumn/> tag when the field is empty rather than it actually being nil